# After created topology in mininet, ONOS GUI does not display the topology

Tags: mininet, onos

After I created the basic topology I checked the ONOS GUI and onos CLI but none of the showing the topology. Please help.
Thanks! Elgin

```
mininet> nodes

available nodes are: 

c0 h1 h2 h3 s1

mininet> pingall

*** Ping: testing ping reachability

h1 -> h2 h3 

h2 -> h1 h3 

h3 -> h1 h2 

*** Results: 0% dropped (6/6 received)

mininet>
```

```
onos> summary

node=10.255.19.102, version=1.12.0 clusterId=default


nodes=1, devices=0, links=0, hosts=0, SCC(s)=0, flows=0, intents=0
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. When mininet started up i observed the following output

> Connecting to remote controller at my_ip_address:6653

Which was curious because i had not started the onos controller.

So i found out what was using port 6653 using: `sudo lsof -i:6653` then killed that process.

Starting the onos controller and mininet, then on onos cli > devices returned correctly